# How to return a subset of multiple collections and its related model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Working with Rails 3 here.

I have a model named 'employee' that has many addresses and has many contacts as such:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :addresses
has_many :contacts
```

What I want to do is to be able to write a single query that returns a specific Employee along with all the addresses created after a specified date and with all contacts created after that same date.  If this is possible, how would I craft such a statement?

I have scopes defined on the address and contact models as such:

```
scope :created_after, lambda { |date_time| where('created_at >= ? or updated_at >= ?', date_time, date_time}
```

... but I can't come up with a way to craft a SINGLE query returning the Employee and a filtered subset of each collection in one swoop.  Any ideas on how to do so efficiently would be appreciated.

Thanks -wg

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
Employee.find(specific_user_id,
              :joins => :addresses, 
              :conditions => { 
                :addresses => ["created_at >= ? OR updated_at >= ?", time, time] 
              }
)
```